# Transient Object Exception in spite of using cascade type all

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, hibernate-mapping, cascading-deletes

I am trying to save the a table with one to many relationship with other table.. The insert query for main table get fired without any problem. After the first query,When the insert query for child is fired, I get the Transient Object Exception. I am using cascadeType all when I am proving the one to many relation .

```
this.getEmailGroupDAO().saveOrUpdate(emailGroup);
this.getEmailGroupDAO().flush();
```

The association in main table is below

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id.emailGroup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true )
private Set<EmailSubGroup> emailSubGroups = new HashSet<EmailSubGroup>(0);
```

I am calling the flush operation after the save or update.I am able to see my generated Id once the save or update is called. Please let me know what is the problem. I have tried all other solutions mentioned in other post.

Below is my other table and its embedded key.

```
@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
@AttributeOverride(name = "groupSysID", column = @Column(name = "SUB_GROUP_SYSID", nullable = false)),
@AttributeOverride(name = "groupSysID", column = @Column(name = "GROUP_SYSID", nullable = false)) })
private EmailSubGroupID id;
```

The table relation.
Parent tbale group can have mutliple sub groups. And the sub group table has composite keys both referring to the parent table sysid. As sub group can itself be a group.

Below is the EmailSubGroupID  class def .

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SUB_GROUP_SYSID", nullable = false)
private EmailGroup emailSubGroup;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_SYSID",  nullable = false,insertable = false,updatable =false)
private EmailGroup emailGroup;
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your `OneToMany`, its `mappedBy`-attribute should reference the variable name of the other side of a bidirectional relationship, here it looks like you are referencing part of an id.

Comment: Not sure, It refers to the parent key which is present in the child key composite reference.Hence mapped by id.emailgroup where id is the embedded key and email group is the variable name referenced in child table composite key. Please correct me if I am wrong sir.